# Ошибка android SDK при попытке собрать проект

Tags: unity3d, android-sdk, unity3d-android

При попытке собрать проект под Android выскакивает ошибка:

> CommandInvokationFailure: Failed to update Android SDK package list.

Как исправить ошибку?

Comment: Версия Unity какая?

Comment: И покажите полный лог ошибки.

Answer (score 0):

1. Есть вот такой [баг репорт](https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/cannot-build-android-player-if-the-colour-space-is-set-to-linear).

   Подозреваю, что у вас Java > 8 версии. Попробуйте даунгрейднуть Java до 7 или 8.
2. Если у вас sdk в директории, к которой нужна права админа, то переместите в папку, для доступа к которой права админа не нужны.